# How can I transfer photos from iPhone to Ubuntu using USB cable?

Tags: mount, iphone

I want to transfer some photos from my iPhone 7 to an Ubuntu 16.04 pc, via USB cable. When I plug the USB cable, it appears in the Files window, but whenever I open the device in the sidebar, a "Loading" text appears at the bottom right corner and after some time the following error message:

> “iPhone” could not be found. Perhaps it has recently been deleted.

I also checked `libimobiledevice` from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778118/iphone-large-file-transfer-via-usb-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1) post. It seems that I have the latest package installed. Following the answer in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704669/how-to-move-files-between-ubuntu-and-iphone), I also tried the following address in the Files:

```
afc://<your iPhone's UDID>/
```

Unfortunately this does not work either, and I get this error:

> Unhandled error message: Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)

How can mount my iPhone to Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe that Apple does something to encrypt data on iPhones/iPods, so that they simply cant be plugged in have files transferred over (similar to a typical USB drive). They use iTunes to decrypt the data. You might have to look for a way to install itunes, or equivilant software that will talk to the iPhone.